# Cannot RDP to IaaS VM- HOST NAME is empty in Azure Dashboard

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

We are running several VMs on Azure with one ADC which is communicating to on-premises DC using site to site VPN connectivity. few days earlier we shut down the VMs in night and now we are not able to take remote of ADC VM and it's hostname is missing from Azure dashboard.

So far, I have tried the following steps:

I have no restrictions on my network since I can RDP to several other Azure VMs. I have restarted the affected VM several times. I changed the RDP endpoint public port and also re-created it. I resized the VM several times but the result is same.

Comment: Have you tried the Powershell command Set-AzureVMAccessExtension?

Comment: Yes, we tried Set-AzureVMExtension command also but still not able to connect to VM.

Comment: I also deleted the VM and created a new one using the same disk,but the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Download the RDP file from the portal
If you look inside the RDP file you should see the actual IP and port of your machine